# Android associate application to file type to allow download in browser

Tags: android, download, mime-types, tiff

I am working on a proof of concept for a .tiff image converter. The first thing I need to do is allow my application to download .tif/.tiff files. They can come from anywhere- http, gmail, local file, etc... And I have no control whether or not the web server will properly identify the file as an image/tiff MIME type.

I cannot download a .tiff file. I believe the way to do this is by enabling my  within my main activity.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.tif" />
</intent-filter>
```

I've looked everywhere and tried numerous suggestions, but can't get it right :(
I am not new to Android dev but I've never encountered a situation where you need to allow a certain file type to be downloaded.

Thank you